# Discretization of 1D Poisson Equation

Tags: poissons-equation

Consider the one-dimensional Poisson’s equation

$$−u''(x) + u(x) = f(x), \hspace{5mm} x \in (a, b),$$
with $u(a) = g_{1}$, $u'(b) = g_2$.

Discretize the equation using the finite element method with piecewise linear basis functions.

I am not sure what to do. 
For the discretization of f(x) I was taught to use the hat function but I am still not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two references that should provide all necessary information, when combined together:

1. [Understanding Galerkin method of weighted residuals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741001/understanding-galerkin-method-of-weighted-residuals)
2. [Are there any two-dimensional quadrature that only uses the values at the vertices of triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763683/are-there-any-two-dimensional-quadrature-that-only-uses-the-values-at-the-vertic)

Assuming that you can do yourself the details of the right hand side in $\,-u''(x)+u(x)=f(x)$ .