# variational formulation of second order differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, finite-element-method

I am given the following differential equation.
Let $\Omega = (a,b)\subset\mathbb{R},\ f:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and 
$$
-u''  + u = f \\
u(a)= \alpha, u(b) = \beta
$$
Since this is an inhomogeneous problem, I choose a function $u_\varphi$ with $u_\varphi|_\Gamma = u|_\Gamma$ such that I can treat the problem like a homogeneous one, by finding a function $u_0$ with $u_0(a)=u_0(b)=0$, such that
$$u = u_\varphi + u_0.$$
The DEQ can then be written as

$$
-(u_0 + u_\varphi)''  + u_0 + u_\varphi = f \\
$$
To find the variational formulation for $u_0$, I test with an arbitrary testfunction $v$ with compact support:

$$\int_\Omega (-(u_0 + u_\varphi)''  + u_0 + u_\varphi)v dx= \int_\Omega fvdx
$$
yielding
$$\int_\Omega (-u_0''+u_0)v dx=\int_\Omega \nabla u_0 \nabla v dx + \int_\Omega u_0v dx = \int_\Omega (f +u_\varphi'' - u_\varphi)vdx
$$
which we usually write compactly as 
$$
a(u_0,v) + \int_\Omega u_0v dx = F(v).
$$
This integral in the last equation bothers me, since I cannot get rid of it. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of this integral?

Comment: I assumed, this stands in the way of solving the problem. But the left side can be written as $a^*(u_0,v)$ with $a^*$ being a bilinear form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem at hand can be reduced to a (somewhat more general) normed problem:
$$
\frac{d^2 T}{d\xi^2} - p^2 T(\xi) = F(\xi)
$$
The left hand side of this normed problem is handled with help of the following references:

1. [Understanding Galerkin method of weighted residuals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741001/understanding-galerkin-method-of-weighted-residuals)
2. [Are there any two-dimensional quadrature that only uses the values at the vertices of triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763683/are-there-any-two-dimensional-quadrature-that-only-uses-the-values-at-the-vertic)

The second reference shows that vertex integration is the most stable one. If we employ this for the *right hand side*, then the integral
$$
\int_0^1 F(\xi)f(\xi)\,d\xi
$$
results in a load vector $\vec{F}$ instead of $0$ . Giving for the system of equations as a whole (read the first reference):
$$
\begin{bmatrix} E_{0,0}^{(1)} & E_{0,1}^{(1)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
E_{1,0}^{(1)} & E_{1,1}^{(1)}+E_{0,0}^{(2)} & E_{0,1}^{(2)} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & E_{1,0}^{(2)} & E_{1,1}^{(2)}+E_{0,0}^{(3)} & E_{0,1}^{(3)} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & E_{1,0}^{(3)} & E_{1,1}^{(3)}+E_{0,0}^{(4)} & E_{0,1}^{(4)} & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\ T_2 \\ T_3 \\ T_4 \\ T_5 \\ \cdots \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} F_1 \\ F_2 \\ F_3 \\ F_4 \\ F_5 \\ \cdots \end{bmatrix}
$$
with the boundary conditions properly imposed.
The original problem - with $x$ and $u$ instead of $\xi$ and $T$ - is recovered by employing the following transformations.
Herewith: $\xi_k \;\rightarrow\; x_k$ and $T_k \;\rightarrow\; u_k$ :
$$
x = (b-a)\xi+a \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 
\begin{cases} x = a \;\leftrightarrow\; \xi = 0 \\ x = b \;\leftrightarrow\; \xi = 1 \end{cases}
\\
u = (\beta-\alpha)T+\alpha \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 
\begin{cases} u = \alpha \;\leftrightarrow\; T = 0 \\ u = \beta \;\leftrightarrow\; T = 1 \end{cases}
$$
**Note.** Variational formulation and Galerkin method are the same in this case.