# Finite Element Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

> [image: Task information]

Hey! I need some help with this task!

**Task:** Derive variational formulation, finite element formulation, and time-marching scheme for problems (1a) - (1d).

Where should I start or how do I solve this??

Thanks in beforehand!

Comment: Are you familiar with the finite element method?

Comment: Yes but is it only to follow the procedure that you make with FEM or is it something else I have to take into account?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the listed methods, then you should learn them first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with finite element method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460293/problem-with-finite-element-method)

Comment: @AbhinavJha, I think it's the other way around, but in any case, it's double posting by the OP

Comment: It's a far too complicated a question to answer in a few minutes. More precise: it will take myself (as a retired engineer) a few hours to set up a decent answer. So I would advice you - or your teacher - to start with much simpler stuff instead of this. For example: [variational formulation of second order differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069174/variational-formulation-of-second-order-differential-equation/) .