# Variational formulation, coercivity of: $ a(v,v) = \int_{\Omega} (\Delta v)^2 + \int_{\partial\Omega} v^2$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, least-squares, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method, coercive

i'm trying to solve the Poisson equation: 
$$
\begin{split}
-\Delta u &= f \quad \text{in } \Omega\\
     u &= g \quad \text{on } \partial \Omega,
\end{split}
$$

where $ \Omega$ is bounded a Lipschitz-continues domain and $u \in H^2(\Omega), f,g \in L^2(\Omega)$. 
The least squares finite element method minimizes the following energy functional:

$$
J(u;f,g) := \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u-f)^2 + \int_{\partial\Omega} (u -g)^2
$$

this method leads to the following variational problem:
$$
a(u,v) = l(v), \quad \forall v \in V \subset H^2(\Omega)
$$
where

$$
\begin{split}
a(u,v) &= \int_{\Omega} \Delta u\Delta v + \int_{\partial\Omega} uv \\ 
     l(v) &= \int_{\Omega} -f\Delta v + \int_{\partial\Omega} gv
\end{split}
$$

It's clear that this bilinear operator is continues. Now i'm trying to proof that $a(v,v)$ is coercive, e.q.

$$
a(v,v) = \int_{\Omega} (\Delta v)^2 + \int_{\partial\Omega} v^2 \geq C\| v\|^2_{H^2(\Omega)} 
$$

It seems to be hard to prove that, so I tried to show this weaker inequality:
$$a(v,v) = \int_{\Omega} (\Delta v)^2 + \int_{\partial\Omega} v^2 \geq C\| v\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} $$
but with no success.

I don't have the opportunity to choose $u \in H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\partial \Omega)$, so i had to add the boundary residual to the energy functional $J$. I guess i'm working with the wrong energy.

This is my first question here and i'm thankful for every hint.

skymath

Comment: Please continue writing the question body.

Comment: i'm finished. Please don't hesitate to ask if i forgot some information

Comment: I think there is a small issue with the question: if $g$ is only in $L^2(\Omega)$, there is no natural interpretation for its value at the boundary. I believe you need at least $g \in H^{1/2}(\Omega)$ to make sense of it using the trace.

Comment: could you please explain in more details?

Comment: You mean: the trace operator i guess only maps $H^{k+2}(\Omega) \rightarrow H^{k+2-1/2}(\partial \Omega)?$ so $g$ has to be from $H^{3/2}$?

Comment: But then i have to use the following energy functional:
$$ J(u;f,g) := \frac{1}{2} \|-\Delta u-f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} +  \frac{1}{2} \|u -g\|^2_{H^{3/2}(\partial\Omega)}$$

which is pretty ugly and not practical :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit rusty and made lots of typos. Why do you think you would need that functional?

Comment: Ah ok, I found a reference on the LSFEM. I wasn't aware of it before, and you're right that norm that appears in the energy functional is related to the space of the data.

Comment: Do you know a way to overcome this impractical functional? I would like to have all the residual-term measured in the $L^2$ norm. Is there some inequality like: 
$$ \| u-g\|_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq \tilde{C}\| u-g\|_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} $$

Comment: No, that certainly does not hold. Think of a more and more oscilatory $(u - g)$, for example.

Comment: Where did $\Delta v$ even come from in the first place? The way that $\nabla v$ enters into the conventional weak formulation of the Poisson equation is by integrating by parts once, which converts $\Delta u$ into $\nabla u$. You can get $\Delta v$ as well by integrating by parts twice instead, but then $\nabla u$ becomes $u$. Either way you don't have $\Delta u \Delta v$.

Comment: It seems to me that if the goal is to minimize that $J$ then you would set $\int_\Omega (-\Delta u - f) v$ and $\int_{\partial \Omega} (u-g) v$ both equal to zero for all $v$ in some suitable class.

Comment: The energy functional i defined on the beginning was:
$$ J(u) = \frac{1}{2}\|-\Delta u - f \|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + \frac{1}{2} \|u - g\|^2_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$$
If I calculate $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dt}J(u+tv)$ i got:
$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dt}J(u+tv) = \left<-\Delta u - f, -\Delta v\right>_{L^2(\Omega)} +  \left<u-g, v\right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$$
after setting it equal to zero, i got:
$$ \left<\Delta u, \Delta v\right>_{L^2(\Omega)} +  \left<u, v\right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)} = \left<f, -\Delta v\right>_{L^2(\Omega)} +  \left<g, v\right>_{L^2(\partial \Omega)}$$

Comment: Beware! The Least Squares Finite Element Method may be very tricky. E.g. [Any employment for the Varignon parallelogram?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023382/any-employment-for-the-varignon-parallelogram) and [What is the difference between Finite Difference Methods, Finite Element Methods and Finite Volume Methods for solving PDEs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424672/what-is-the-difference-between-finite-difference-methods-finite-element-methods/2401159#2401159)

Answer (score 1):

The first coercivity inequality does not hold. Take, for example, the disk-shape domain $\Omega = \{x, y: x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ and consider a sequence of boundary data $g_n$, $n \in \mathbb R$, defined by $g_n = \cos(n\theta(x, y))$, where $\theta(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the angle of the argument in $[0, 2\pi]$. Take $v_n$ as being the solution of
\begin{align} 
- \Delta v_n = 0, \qquad & \text{in $\Omega$}, \\
v_n = g_n, \qquad & \text{in $\partial \Omega$}.
\end{align}
Clearly,
$$
\int_{\Omega} (\Delta v_n)^2 + \int_{\partial\Omega} v_n^2 = \int_{\partial \Omega} g_n^2  \leq C.
$$
If the first coercivity inequality you wrote was true,
it would imply:
$$
\|v_n\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C,
$$
and thus, by the trace inequality
$$
\|v_n\|_{H^{m}(\partial \Omega)} = \|g_n\|_{H^m(\partial\Omega)}\leq C, \qquad 0 \leq m \leq 3/2.
$$
Given the form of $g_n$, this is clearly false for $m = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for that counter example. I also guessed, i chose the wrong energy functional. I'm trying to find other energy, so that i got the coercivity proven.

Comment: I think you do still get continuity with the  $3/2$ Sobolev space, but coercivity seems a bit trickier...

Comment: last time i read about this inverse inequality, i dont know exactly where:
$$ \|u\|_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq C h^{-3/2} \|u\|_{L^{2}(\partial \Omega)}$$

would you say with the estimate obove, i would be able to prove this weaker coercivity:
$$a(v,v) \geq C(h) \|v\|_{H^2(\Omega)}$$

Comment: You need to specify the spaces in which you think these inequalities are valid; what is $h$ here?